# Detecting very high voltages

Tags: current-measurement, high-voltage, voltage-detector

I work for a plastics molding company and we manufacture containers that we need to verify do not have holes in them. I am looking design a fixture that will apply a very high voltage (about 15-30KV) to the surface of the product to see if the electricity finds a path through the material.  I then want to sound an alarm if a path is detected.  I'm struggling to find a way to detect the current flow without blowing out (due to the high voltage) the electronics. I am a quality engineer, not an EE but I am a life long electronics hobbyist.  I have considered making a rudimentary optocoupler, putting a neon or xenon bulb in a box with a photocell but I am hoping for a more elegant solution. What would you suggest?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to have an internal and external electrode the shape of the container to do this? An air pressure or vacuum decay test sounds much safer and the equipment is available commercially. Search for leak testers.

Comment: That depends on the shape,  hole sizes, and other physical properties and ability to seal edge.   Show example.

Comment: May want to reach out to folks that test lineman gloves and see how they go about it.  [Here is link to one](https://www.epcor.com/products-services/power/Pages/high-voltage-testing.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> I work for a plastics molding company and we manufacture containers that we need to verify do not have holes in them. I am looking design a fixture that will apply a very high voltage (about 15-30KV) to the surface of the product to see if the electricity finds a path through the material. I then want to sound an alarm if a path is detected.

That sounds like condom manufacturing!

> I'm struggling to find a way to detect the current flow without blowing out (due to the high voltage) the electronics.

Large resistors: "blowing out" happens because high current flows. The relationship between current and voltage is I = U/R, so pick a large R.

In fact, pick two R, one large, one small, and build a *voltage divider*.

Driving a commercially available octocoupler (i.e. not the split thing that you described, but an LED and a photodiode in the same black package) with the output of your voltage divider might still be a good idea to protect your system if something should go wrong with the high voltage.

Comment: Marcus Muller it could be anything but condom manufacturing.

Comment: @HelenaWells I know! It's just that this is something that is often shown in educational material as an example for voltage/continuity-based testing, because it's such a prestiguous thing, and thus, it might help Victor find reference material to point him to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are High voltage probes like Tektronix P6015 and similar. You hook this probe to a DSO that has a possibility to output a signal pass/fail and trigger the start of test. If this is a part o production line, then I do think you should use devices from reputable manufacturers, not a DIY.

Comment: I agree. If anything, just for reliability I would avoid DIY. Also some safety concerns.  And high voltage can come with lots of other problems. So with a product from a reputable manufacturer comes support and app notes.